# UIAutomation for iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ui-automation, ios-ui-automation

Does `UIAutomation` work for testing on the iPhone devices and can I do it without the xCode for the project?

Is there another tool that can test without the xCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do UIAutomation for iPhone device with certain constraints. A new tool in iPhone know as **[Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)** which is now more powerful for testing.

For a good walkthrough go through the link http://mobileorchard.com/find-iphone-memory-leaks-a-leaks-tool-tutorial/

Comment: This does not answer the question; can you do it without Xcode. But the rest of answer is good.

Comment: @JohanKarlsson: May you be correct but this is possible without opening Xcode. But unfortunately Instruments is shipped along with Xcode only. so this is partially correct i think so... But i think this helped to "user943302"

Comment: It's more that it doesn't provide an answer because the article linked to is about leak hunting with Instruments not using UIAutomation.